# Access Logs Pig Job. Count and Distinct Count

Tags: apache-pig

I have TBs of HTTP access logs that I'm trying to analyze for historical reference. I'm trying to get the daily number of UNIQUE visitors (IPs) and the daily number of hits.

If this were in MySQL I'd just do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) from access_logs union
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ip)) from access_logs
```

Any way to do something similar with one job, so I don't have to do the map work a second time?

I know this wont work, but this is kind of the functionality I'm looking for.

```
X = (fqdn:chararray,ip:chararray,date:chararray,time:chararray,uri:chararray,ua:chararray);
Y = COUNT(X);
Z = COUNT(DISTINCT(X.IP);
OUT = UNION Y,Z;
STORE OUT into ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all of the records in the input, than you need you use GROUP ALL, which creates one bag. Also for performance reasons it use an accumulator DISTINCT function org.apache.pig.builtin.Distinct

```
X = load 'path' as (fqdn:chararray,ip:chararray,date:chararray,time:chararray,uri:chararray,ua:chararray);
IPs = FOREACH X GENERATE ip; // project early for performance reasons
GRP = group IPs all;
OUT = foreach GRP generate COUNT(IPs) as all_cnt, COUNT(org.apache.pig.builtin.Distinct(IPs.ip)) as distinct_cnt;
```

If you have too many IPs and you get memory related exceptions, than you can do something like this:

```
X = load 'path' as (fqdn:chararray,ip:chararray,date:chararray,time:chararray,uri:chararray,ua:chararray);
IPs = FOREACH X GENERATE ip; // project early for performance reasons
Dist_IPs = distinct IPs;
GRP_DIST = group Dist_IPs all;
DIST = foreach GRP_DIST generate COUNT(GRP_DIST) as cnt, 'dist' as category;

GRP_ALL = group IPs all;
ALL = foreach GRP_ALL generate COUNT(GRP_ALL)as cnt, 'all' as category;

OUT = union DIST, ALL;
```